# I am trying to use database first approach in Entity Framework .NET using Oracle database

Tags: entity-framework, oracle-sqldeveloper, visual-studio-2019, ef-database-first

i am using visual studio 2019 and have created an C# console application, added "Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore" and "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" packages. Oracle database is already available in Server Explorer. Now i want create Models from the existing Oracle database tables using Scaffold-DbContext.

**NOTE: I AM BOUND TO USE OLD 2.2.6 VERSION OF "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" OTHERWISE IT GENERATES ERROR AS:**

```
1. Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes.

2. Version conflict detected for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.
```

Need to execute this sort of command:
Scaffold-DbContext "User Id=*****;Password=*****;Data Source=<*****>;" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models

Comment: So what's the question.  It looks like Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore requires EF Core 2.x.  See the package dependencies here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore/

Comment: I think you want to do a database first model.  This approach is no longer recommended.

Comment: @fireydude scaffold-dbcontext is the "database first" workflow for EF Core.

Comment: @Syed Aamir un Nabi, did you get any solution or output?